# Java JAXB Marshalling not working

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

This is my save function in mainApp:

```
public void saveUizvatelov() {
    System.out.println("saveujem" + uzivatelia.size());
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(UzivatelSave.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        // Wrapping our person data.
        UzivatelSave wrapper = new UzivatelSave();
        wrapper.setUzivatel(uzivatelia);

        // Marshalling and saving XML to the file.
        m.marshal(wrapper, new FileOutputStream("data.xml"));

    } catch (Exception e) { // catches ANY exception
    }
}
```

My xml file is empty after I save, but it should contain 2 persons(Uzivatel). This is the output I expect:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Uzivatelia>
    <Uzivatel/>
    <Uzivatel/>
</Uzivatelia>
```

The JAXB entity

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Uzivatelia")
public class UzivatelSave {
    private List<Uzivatel> uzivatel;

    @XmlElement(name = "Uzivatel")
    public List<Uzivatel> getUzivatel() {
        return uzivatel;
    }

    /**
     * @param uzivatel the uzivatel to set
     */
    public void setUzivatel(List<Uzivatel> uzivatel) {
        this.uzivatel = uzivatel;
    }

}
```

Can someone give me advice for saving when I have multiple observable lists full of objects?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Show your JAXB-annotated entity classes here

Comment: UzivatelSave should be answer for u :)

Comment: Try setting `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on the `UzivatelSave` class. Apart from that, your code here seems Ok. Verify that the entities have their fields properly set

Comment: fields are ok but I tried : @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) before "public class UzivatelSave {" but it cause in part "public void saveUizvatelov() {" that program jumped on catch exception. Still not working.

Comment: Are you sure there are 2 items in the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you haven't added any items to the collection.  This is why nothing is getting marshalled.  The following works for me:

### Java Model

**UzivatelSave**

Same as from your question.

**Uzivatel**

```
public class Uzivatel {
}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(UzivatelSave.class);

        List<Uzivatel> uzivatelArrayList = new ArrayList<Uzivatel>();
        uzivatelArrayList.add(new Uzivatel());
        uzivatelArrayList.add(new Uzivatel());

        UzivatelSave uzivatelSave = new UzivatelSave();
        uzivatelSave.setUzivatel(uzivatelArrayList);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(uzivatelSave, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Uzivatelia>
    <Uzivatel/>
    <Uzivatel/>
</Uzivatelia>
```

Comment: wrapper.setUzivatel(uzivatelia); uzivatelia is observablelist of Uzivatel i copy-pasted your code still nothing. But it depends on number of useres I have. When I have 3 users theres 3 times <Uzivatel/>. I think its creating row for it but it cant fill it with data.

Comment: @MatThe - The collection items aren't appearing, or they are appearing as empty elements.

Comment: these object have atributes like StringProperty and BooleanProperty is that ok or its that problem ?

Comment: @MatThe - That may be a problem. You may need to create an `XmlAdapter`, something like:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html

Comment: its veryfied problem is String and Boolean property. im trying use xmladapter but im confused where i should paste "@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringPropertyAdapter.class, type=String.class)})" ??

Comment: in this tutorial http://code.makery.ch/java/javafx-8-tutorial-part5/ he is usin stringProperty and it works could be problem in JDK version ?